# Tables rates are not displaying Region Wise for Country(INDIA) while checkout?

Tags: php, magento

Magento displaying Table rates before checkout region wise but not displaying after checkout process Shipping method is displaying: "Sorry no quotes avilable for this order" Error message.

Uploaded csv file with Country code, Region, Zip code, Weight and price. 
Only country code is working but not Region.

I am using Weight vs Destination method in magento 1.9.4 verison

Comment: when you found the solution yourself, then write it as an answer and mark it as accepted answer. So anyone else looking for this problem will see immediately that an answer/solution exists!

Comment: Can you edit your question with a bit clearer grammer on the problem? Even attaching images might help others in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution. State was not mandatory field so updated one more entry in csv file country code with * in region field